# How do I add a linerenderer require attribute?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DrawLines : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Apply these values in the editor
    public LineRenderer LineRenderer;
    public Transform target;

    void Start()
    {
        // set the color of the line
        LineRenderer.startColor = Color.red;
        LineRenderer.endColor = Color.red;

        // set width of the renderer
        LineRenderer.startWidth = 0.3f;
        LineRenderer.endWidth = 0.3f;

        // set the position
        LineRenderer.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
        LineRenderer.SetPosition(1, target.position);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Instead the  public LineRenderer I want to add at the top a require so it will add automatic the linerenderer component when attaching the script to a gameobject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [RequireComponent attribute.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html) This requires a game object to have a specified component in order for this component to be added and will automatically add both components when necessary.

Usage:

`[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))] public class DrawLines : MonoBehaviour { }`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `this.gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();` to add component in realtime;